# Audio mixing : crosstalk calculation

Tags: audio, crosstalk

[Here](http://www.rane.com/note109.html) is an interesting article about mixing stereo.
Most important issues when mixing stereo are :

- interaction between channel
- crosstalk
- noise

Interaction between channel is explained [here](https://sound-au.com/articles/audio-mixing.htm) in 1.0 with passive mixing, from that :

> It would be possible to make the output impedance of all equipment
>   much higher, so direct mixing would not cause any circuit stress. The
>   problem would then be that we are back to the position we had when
>   valve gear ruled ... high impedance causes relatively high noise and
>   high frequency rolloff with long cables. Cables can also become
>   microphonic, and this is why so many pieces of valve kit used output
>   transformers - to provide a low impedance (optionally balanced) output
>   to prevent the very problems described. Low output impedance is here
>   to stay, as are mixers, so now we can examine the methods in more
>   detail.

But for crosstalk, in the mixing passive circuit, how do we calculate it? We can find different methods to measure it. but for simple mixing circuits I did not found any documents describing how it be computed.

We can find an example in [here](http://www.rane.com/note109.html) :

> The problem arising from using all three outputs (the two original and
>   the new summed output) is one of channel separation, or crosstalk. If
>   the driving unit truly has zero output impedance, than channel
>   separation is not degraded by using this summing box. However, when
>   dealing with real-world units you deal with finite output impedances
>   (ranging from a low of 47 ohms to a high of 600 ohms). Even a low
>   output impedance of 47 ohms produces a startling channel separation
>   spec of only 27 dB, i.e., the unwanted channel is only 27 dB below the
>   desired signal. **(Technical details: the unwanted channel, driving
>   through the summing network, looks like 1011.3 ohms driving the 47
>   ohms output impedance of the desired channel, producing 27 dB of
>   crosstalk.)**

Some technical details are given, but it's not clear to me. Can someone give detailed steps to compute crosstalk for this example? A simulation example could also helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can someone give detailed steps to compute crosstalk for this example?

It's quite simple. If signal A has an output impedance of 47 ohms and is passively mixed with a signal B using two 500 ohm resistors then signal B impregnates signal A because there is a simple potential divider.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjoPPJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If signal A is zero volts (to take the simple case) and signal B is 1 volt, then the voltage appearing at signal A (after the 47 ohm resistor) is: -

1 volt x 47/1047 = 44.9 mV.

This 44.9 mV shouldn't be there ideally i.e. it is cross contamination and, if you worked out what this factor is in decibels then that comes to -26.96 dB.

The way to overcome this is not to bodge-mix by using a passive resistor network but to use a virtual earth summing amplifier.

Comment: thanks. In this example, can we say that conditions to have crosstalk are : input source impedance > 0 and a signal from source = 0V ? Another question, in some cases, we can see such summing circuits : http://techtalk.parts-express.com/filedata/fetch?id=1170517&d=1449579955 , what is R3 role?

Comment: In this example you will get cross talk whnever the source impedances are > 0. In the picture you linked, R3 adds attenuation to the overall mixed output signal and reduces cross talk by the same amount.

Comment: Thanks for your reponse. For crosstalk conditions, from calculation, we get Unwanted crosstalk on A = R2/(2*(R1 + R2)) * (Vsignal1 - Vsignal2), so we do not have any crosstalk when R2 = 0 (or Vsignal1 = Vsignal2)  . When doing a stereo to mono mixing, with same sources impedances, we will keep an output voltage of (Vsignal1 - Vsignal2)/2, so crosstalk must be taken into account only if signal 1 or signal 2 used somewhere in circuit, for example to drive a speaker. Is it right? For R3 role, could you detail your response with some calculations?

Comment: Yes, everything you say is correct. Regarding the calculation, are you familiar with superposition theory? If not then you need to take a look at it because it shows how multiple voltage sources act to produce a "mixed" voltage.